# How can I pipe a directory name to Set-Location cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find a directory of some command, and then change current directory to that found directory.
The below command gives me a directory:

```
Get-Item -Path $(where.exe cmd.exe) | Select -Property Directory 

Directory
---------
C:\Windows\System32
```

And now I try to pipe this directory to Set-Location cmdlet, but I receive an error:

```
Get-Item -Path $(where.exe cmd.exe) | Select -Property Directory | Set-Location

Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{Directory=C' does not exist.
At line:1 char:67
+ ... -Path $(where.exe cmd.exe) | Select -Property Directory |Set-Location
+                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{Directory=C:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

How can I do this? Please help.

Comment: Heads up, I've made an addition at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-Item -Path $(where.exe cmd.exe) | Select -ExpandProperty Directory | Set-Location
```

This one deserves a bit of an explanation.

When used in the file system, `Get-Item` returns a `FileInfo` or `DirectoryInfo` object, depending. They both have a `Directory` property, so far so good.

`Select-Object SomeProperty` does *not*, by default, give you whatever value `SomeProperty` has. It gives you a *new* object (a `PSObject`) of which `SomeProperty` is the only member. This is to support the case where you do `Select-Object SomeProperty, SomeOtherProperty`.

If you want the raw value of a single property of the input object, you must explicitly say so. That's what `Select-Object -ExpandProperty SomeProperty` does. (Corollary: You can't do `Select-Object -ExpandProperty SomeProperty, SomeOtherProperty`.)

`Set-Location` expects a string. When you pass something else, e.g. a `PSObject`, it will convert it to string. And the string representation of a `PSObject` does not work as a path, even if it's a `PSObject` that only contains a path.

Another way to get the raw value - direct property access - would work as well (this is what you might have had in mind from the start):

```
(Get-Item -Path $(where.exe cmd.exe)).Directory | Set-Location
```

And since we have established that `Set-Location` expects a string, this also works:

```
$(where.exe cmd.exe) | Split-Path -Parent | Set-Location
```

---

By the way, there is a convenient way to replace the somewhat awkward `where.exe` call with something that's PowerShell native - `Get-Command`:

```
Set-Location ((Get-Command cmd).Source | Split-Path -Parent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody mentioned it - you can use a pipeline-bound parameter expression:

```
Get-Item -Path $(where.exe cmd.exe) |Set-Location -LiteralPath {$_.Directory.FullName}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with get-command.  Split-Path sends the directory byvalue to the path parameter of Set-Location.

```
Get-Command cmd | Split-Path | Set-Location
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select a single property, 
this one works too (without encapsulating it in pscustomobject):

```
get-item -path (where.exe cmd.exe) | % Directory | Set-Location
```

"%" is the foreach-object command. And the syntax only 
works with *one* property. Otherwise you have to put it in braces ...

Regards, Martin